# View containers move around and change sizes

Tags: react-native, expo

I have the same component in multiple screens, which I navigate to through React navigation. I'm using Tabnavigator.

On the first screen, the View containers move around if the text is too long. I have a fixed flex-size on my view containers, but it doesn't take that into consideration. The strange is, it's only on the first screen. A gif to show you what I mean.

https://gfycat.com/KaleidoscopicEasygoingApisdorsatalaboriosa

I have linked a Snack to show you my code: 
https://snack.expo.io/@cronnay/show-inconsistency

I've checked if it's because of the scrollview I have, and I was inconsistent with my design on the scrollviews. but they all have the same styling.

What the heck is going on?

EDIT: Uploaded new gif that shows that I navigate to same component through two different ways. And it makes the design screw up.
https://gfycat.com/HappyPracticalAustralianfreshwatercrocodile

Comment: There is no problem with the expo link you shared, perhaps you add the complete code to it.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the strange part. It works fine on the Snack. It is the entire code for my component. I can add scrollview the scrollview

Comment: You can make it as shown in your gif and see if the issue persists.

Comment: The issue isn't with the component. It could be with the navigator. Here is a new gif, and you'll see that I go to the same component, just through two different ways. https://gfycat.com/HappyPracticalAustralianfreshwatercrocodile